# kubectl get events only for a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I run `kubectl -n abc-namespace describe pod my-pod-zl6m6`, I get a lot of information about the pod along with the Events in the end.

Is there a way to output just the Events of the pod either using `kubectl describe` or `kubectl get` commands?

**Edit**:

This can now (kubernetes 1.29) be achieved via the following command -

`kubectl -n abc-namespace events --for pod/my-pod-zl6m6`

*All the answers below can be ignored as they refer to older versions of kubernetes*

Answer (score 334, accepted):

You can use the `event` command of `kubectl`.

To filter for a specific pod you can use a field-selector:

```
kubectl get event --namespace abc-namespace --field-selector involvedObject.name=my-pod-zl6m6
```

To see what fields are possible you can use `kubectl describe` on any event.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I get:
`Error: unknown flag: --field-selector`

Comment: The official documentation mentioned field-selector since 1.12. I could not find any hint since when this is supported (found some tickets from 2015). So check your kubectl version and the help output to see what is possible with your kubectl version.

Comment: yeah.  i have an older version.  :(

Comment: @toddcscar you can still use more updated version of kubectl with an older server version: for example this will work on kubectl v1.14 against a v1.11 API

Comment: @toddcscar were you using `get` or `describe`? That happened to me because I was trying first with `describe` and there is no such option in that command

Comment: This command will not work correctly if your cluster contains some additional objects with the same name as your Pod in the specified namespace. To be precise, use the following command: `kubectl get event --namespace abc-namespace --field-selector involvedObject.name=my-pod-zl6m6,involvedObject.kind=Pod`

Comment: And if you want to watch for changes: ` watch -d 'kubectl  get event --field-selector involvedObject.name=MY_POD_NAME | tail' `

Answer (score 73):

**This answer gives context to [@mszalbach's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931477/7653022)'s answer.**

1. You should first understand the data structure of the events object. You can use `kubectl get events --output json` to check the data structure.

   ```json
   $ kubectl get events --output json
   {
       "apiVersion": "v1",
       "items": [
           {
               "apiVersion": "v1",
               "count": 259,
               "eventTime": null,
               "firstTimestamp": "2020-04-15T12:00:46Z",
               "involvedObject": {                 <------ **this**
                   "apiVersion": "v1",
                   "fieldPath": "spec.containers{liveness}",
                   "kind": "Pod",               
                   "name": "liveness-exec",        <------ **this**
                   "namespace": "default",
                   "resourceVersion": "725991",
                   "uid": "3f497636-e601-48bc-aec8-72b3edec3d95"
               },
               ...
   ```
2. Then, you can do something like this

   ```
   kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=[...]`.
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the extra context on how to understand the `--field-selector`... fields :)

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/

Answer (score 30):

Why not display all events and grep for your podname:

```
kubectl get events --all-namespaces  | grep -i $podname
```

Comment: While this provides the results, I'd prefer the one with `field-selector` switch :)

Comment: Of course, no doubt that is the cleaner solution. Learned about the `--field-selector` switch just now.

Comment: you couldnt even grep the podname, because it is not printed with the `kubectl get events` command

Answer (score 13):

You can describe you pod and then grep the number of lines after your Events. You can add a watch if you want to monitor it.

```
watch "kubectl describe pod my-pod-zl6m6 | grep -A20 Events"
```

Comment: is `watch` a plugin?

Comment: no watch is not any kind of plugin even you can use "-w " option and get the same result

Comment: to be explicit: watch is a stand alone tool. On mac `brew install watch`

Answer (score 12):

All events specific to Deployment

```
kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=$DEPLOYMENT_NAME -n $NAMESPACE
```

All events except Normal

```
get events --field-selector type!=Normal -A
```

Comment: Thanks! This also works for a pod name like this `kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=$POD_NAME -n $NAMESPACE`

Comment: i dont think it works for a deployment though

Comment: it works

❯ kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=nignx
19s         Normal   ScalingReplicaSet        deployment/nignx   Scaled up replica set nignx-8f49b6b4b to 1

Answer (score 12):

There is a new kubectl command which does what you asked for:

```
kubectl events --for pod/my-pod-zl6m6
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_events/

Comment: It is still alpha after 1 year.

Comment: Not exactly sure when it's gone out of alpha. But currently it's live - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_events/

Comment: Thanks for the reminder; `kubectl events` was promoted to beta in 2022 and released in Kubernetes 1.28 in July 2023.  https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/4018

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the Event Messages in a short and clear view, [@mszalbach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363517/mszalbach) [answer is the best one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931477/7653022).

But if you want all Events with all their elements to be completely displayed you can run:

```
kubectl describe event [POD_NAME] --namespace [POD's_NAMESPACE]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) tool. With the following command:

```
kubectl get events -n namespace-name -ojson | jq '.items[] | select ((.involvedObject.name=="pod-name") and (.involvedObject.kind=="Pod"))'
```

Note that I used an additional condition in the select clause `.involvedObject.kind=="Pod"`, to filter out all non-Pod objects with the same name and namespace as Pod we wanted.

Be aware of that while using the solution included in [the-best-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931113/kubectl-get-events-only-for-a-pod/51931477#51931477). You can just add the additional filter-selector to the command as well.

```
kubectl get event --namespace abc-namespace --field-selector involvedObject.name=my-pod-zl6m6,involvedObject.kind=Pod
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `kubectl events` command for this (not the `kubectl get events`)

Example:

`kubectl events --for pod/nginx`

Output:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON      OBJECT      MESSAGE
10m         Normal   Pulling     Pod/nginx   Pulling image "nginx"
10m         Normal   Scheduled   Pod/nginx   Successfully assigned default/nginx to node01
9m58s       Normal   Pulled      Pod/nginx   Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 3.811s (3.811s including waiting)
9m58s       Normal   Created     Pod/nginx   Created container nginx
9m58s       Normal   Started     Pod/nginx   Started container nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

> For me, the other answers look good. But, It's valuable to understand the
> under the hood.

### Step 1. How to view original data? Because k8s will automatically by default convert `json` data from `etcd` into readable.

- So you should use the command like this to view the both content and structure of each item.

```
kubectl get events -o json -n default
```

Then you will get many items like this
[image]

### Step 2. Using [--field-selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) combine with the value you want to access from the output above like this

**The value you want to access is `"involvedObject.name"` JSONPATH format**

[image]

#### ==> Final command

```
kubectl get events --field-selector=involvedObject.name=demo-deployment-5f4fd5649b-rks6f
```

**Output**
[image]